# How to forward an email downloaded by PHP and IMAP?

Tags: php, email, imap, forwarding

I'm writing a script to read email and distribute it to different email addresses depending on the TO address.  All email comes to one address, but I cannot seem to figure out how to forward an email, or create a new email and include all of the relevant message body.

Right now I'm downloading the email using IMAP and using imap_fetchbody to get the email contents;

```
$email_body = imap_fetchbody($imapconnex, $msgnumber, 1);
```

Some email bodies don't display correctly, and others contain short lines with an `=` symbol at the end, causing the content to not display correctly. Also, I'm seeing random `A0` printed in my email bodies randomly.

My plan was to use PHP's mail() function to send the email to where I want it to go and change the From address to the real From address. That would work for my needs, but I cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the correct body, format it and send it.

Here's my code that I'm using to send the email:

```
$header = imap_fetch_overview($imapconnex, $search[$i]);
$email_subject = $header[0]->subject;
$email_head = imap_fetchbody($imapconnex, $search[$i], 0); 
$email_body = imap_fetchbody($imapconnex, $search[$i], 1); 
mail("me@mydomain.com", $email_subject, $email_body, $email_head);
```

The headers seem to be forwarding fine, but the main body of the message is still displaying with `=` and `A0` symbols.

Comment: It sounds like you are copying the body of the original mail into a new mail but you are missing the headers, `Content-Transfer-Encoding` which would cause the `=` and `A0` symptoms you are seeing. If you are resending mail, you should probably copy most, if not all of the headers from the original mail. If you are forwarding, you should include the original mail intact with all its headers as a MIME body part in the new mail.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's interesting about the content-transfer-encoding.

Comment: I've fixed the headers of my code (thank you Celada) but am still having issues with the body displaying `=` and `A0`. I've noticed that using my code I am not getting `Content-Transfer-Encoding` in the original headers.

Comment: I tried adding `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` to my headers, but it's still the same output.

Comment: If you have `=A0` and stuff like that in the raw body of the message, you almost certainly have a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` in the original message which is `quoted-printable`. Perhaps you are not getting a faithful version of the original header. I forget the IMAP syntax to download the raw original email, but maybe you need to use that instead of `imap_fetch_overview`. You need to copy **all** of the relevant headers (`Content-Type`, `MIME-Version`, etc...) for it to work. In fact, the simplest and most correct thing to do is just to copy all headers from the original email.

Answer (score 2):

Marc

Nice answer and provides a simple solution. It can also handle plain text with some  minor changes.

```
$mtype = array('text', 'multipart', 'message', 'application', 'audio', 
               'image', 'video', 'model', 'other');
$mailstructure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $msgno, FT_UID); //
$type = $mailstructure->type;
if ($type == 1 && $mailstructure->ifparameters == 1) {
    $parameters = $mailstructure->parameters;
    $attribute = $parameters[0]->attribute;
    $value = $parameters[0]->value;
    echo $attribute . "//" . $value . "<br />";
}
# prepare the mail
$to="";
$subject="";
//   line below (may) not (be) needed
//   $body="\r\nThis is a multipart message in MIME format.\r\n";
$body = imap_body($inbox, $uid, FT_UID);
$headers ="From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .="Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n";
$headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .="Content-Type: " . $mtype[$mailstructure->type] . '/'
         . strtolower($mailstructure->subtype) . ";\r\n";
if ($type == 1) { // multipart
    $headers .= "\t boundary=\"" . $value . "\""."\r\n";
}
$sendmail = imap_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Today the mostly messages are multipart.  I use this and its works.

```
$mailstructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $uid, FT_UID); //
$type = $mailstructure->type;
if ($type == 1 && $mailstructure->ifparameters == 1) {
    $subtype = strtolower($mailstructure->subtype);
    echo "SubType is" . $subtype . "<br />";
    $parameters = $mailstructure->parameters;
    $attribute = $parameters[0]->attribute;
    $value = $parameters[0]->value;
    echo $attribute . "//" . $value . "<br />";
    # prepare the mail
$to="";
$subject="";
    $body="\r\nThis is a multipart message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $body.=imap_body($inbox, $uid, FT_UID);
    $headers ="From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .="Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n";
    $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/" . $subtype . ";
        \t boundary=\"" . $value . "\""."\r\n";
   $sendmail = imap_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

}